# custom url instead of having localhost

Tags: macos, url, xampp

I have a folder called example inside htdocs in XAMPP , so I access my url with `localhost/example/` . How can I have just `example/` instead of `localhost/example/` when I type my url ? Thanks in advance!

I've tried editing DocumentRoom in apache htdocs and it didn't work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if that helps you, but you have to set the html root into your example folder to be able to use localhost/ only. Maybe you can move all contents of the example folder to the parent directory and try again.

If you want to use a real URL like example.com/ instead of localhost/ you can edit your hosts file

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

and add the following lines to the end:

```
127.0.0.1    www.example.com
127.0.0.1    example.com
```